# How to change grub black screen

Tags: linux-mint, grub2

I'm using dual boot Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon and Windows XP.
So I want change grub2 black screen and I've tried to install gfxmenu theme for grub but it is not working; I see it's not installed in grub but in boot directory.
I've tried also grub-customizer tool but it also does not work.

ftp://cathbard.com/binary/cathbard-grub-mint-ladder_0.0.1-1_all.deb

Above link is a file of grub ladder that I've installed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have `grub2`. If grub-customize does not work, you will have to hack the files manually or install a ready theme and customize that.

Please check `/etc/default/grub`, this is the file for your theme.

You can set `GRUB_BACKGROUND` to the background image you want (you might have to add that line if there is none).

```
GRUB_BACKGROUND=/path/to/file
```

You can toggle the gfxmode by running `vbeinfo` in grub: reboot, in grub, hit `c` and type `vbeinfo`. Select an appropriate graphics mode, write it down and exit out of grub to boot into GNU/Linux. Uncomment `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480`, set it to your preferred mode (this is mine, do not use on your system if not in YOUR output of vbeinfo):

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1440x900x24
```

Icons:

Inspect `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
For each entry you will have one or more classes.
You can put icons for a class in `/boot/grub/themes/icons`

Ready themes:

**https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=141631**

As you see on that page, simply copy them to `/boot/grub/themes` (you might have to create that directory first)

If you still have issues, please post:

Please post `$ cat /etc/default/grub` and `$ ls /boot/grub/themes/`

Comment: this not helpful for me . My theme installed in boot directory named as gfxmenu and you telling about default theme.

Comment: And 05_debian_theme saying if desktop-base is installed ! And this is only for debian! I've grub2 . I want install theme that I mentioned in question. Theme installed in boot named as gfxmenu I want apply it.

Comment: I have added gfxmenu to your question, "change black screen" sounded like you wanted to add a background image, to me at least.